# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Analytics"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5.1

I have tried almost every solution on this website, but unfortunately no progress. 
I have all the frameworks added in my project and all the .m files are in my project. Still I am facing this undefined symbols error. 
[image]

**Details:**

I am trying to convert an old cocos2d project to version 2.1, therefore I have copied most of the files from old project to new project. I have many warnings complaining about deprecated methods, and only 3 linker errors.

Comment: Why not to cocos2d 3.1?

Comment: @trojanfoe because I just want to add 4 inch support to my game, updating to 3.1 will take a lot of effort, as api has changed a lot since then.

Comment: Isn't the class called `FlurryAnalytics`? http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/iOS/interface_flurry_analytics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `VAGameScreen+StateManager.m` you are accessing to `Analytics` class which is probably not added to the project.

Comment: Please check target dependencies for this file.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a .a file, forgot to copy into project while I was copying other files. Xcode automatically added that to compile sources when I dragged the file into Xcode.

Comment: That sounds like what Sviatoslav Yakymiv said.